# Regex match only the third occurrence of a pattern

Tags: regex

The example text is as follows:

```
01MAR2015 01MAR2015 Example Example 
02MAR2015 Example Example Example
03MAR2015 Example Example $2.45
```

I want to select all the text from the third date (second row) all the way to the dollar amount. I don't know how to skip the first two dates. Thanks for any help.

Expected output:

```
02MAR2015 Example Example Example
03MAR2015 Example Example $2.45
```

What I have for now:

```
([0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}) # to match the date
((\d)*\.(\d){2}) # to match the dollar amount
(?<=([0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}){2})\1.*((\d)*\.(\d){2}) # my attempt
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I have added those details.

Comment: I am using autohotkey script. Although I prefer the regex to be language independent.

Comment: [`^(?:.+?(?=\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{4})){2}((?:(?!\$\d).)*(?:\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?))`](https://regex101.com/r/2wg1hO/1) group 1

Comment: Perhaps [like this](https://regex101.com/r/OsFHVH/1/)

Comment: Try `(?<=\n)[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[\w\W]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need to match the text starting at the second line. In AHK, you may use PCRE compatible patterns.

Use

```
(?<=\n)[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[\w\W]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l3Oxsm/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=\n)` - matching will start after a newline
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `[A-Z]{3}` - 3 uppercase letters
- `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
- `[\w\W]*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible.